# Is sending a ticket barcode in an email illegal?

Tags: civimail, civievent

According to [this post](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/12673/prior-art-for-e-ticketing-with-a-barcode-image-via-the-web), sending a barcode in a e-ticket is patented. So is it illegal?